# How to get index of duplicates in array?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I would like to know how to get the index of two or more objects that is a duplicate in an array. How would i do this in swift?

My array looks like this : [1, 2, 3, 1]
I would then like to return the index of 1, since they are duplicates.(0, 3)

I have tried to find any answers regarding this, but I could not find any answers. Therefore I hope I can get an answer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow! When posting a question, please include your own research and what you have tried already. If you aren't willing to do the work to find your answer, you shouldn't expect others to as well, however, after having done the work you can and following the [ask]  guidelines, the Stack Overflow will be more than happy to help you on a specific point that you're stuck at. Until then, this question sounds like you are asking people to code for you, which is not the purpose of SO.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255978/swift-generic-array-function-to-find-all-indexes-of-elements-not-matching-item It's essentially what you want, you just need to change the implementation to return the matching indexes instead of the non-matching indexes.

Comment: I read the link, but i did not understand how i would change the implementation to return the matching indexes instead of the non-matching ones?

Answer (score -1):

I did find a solution!

```
names = ["Shrek", "Shrek", "Pinocchio"]
for name in names{
        print(names.index(of: name))
    }
```

Prints(0,0,2) because names has to duplicates

Comment: Well, it just prints the indices of the first occurrences of every word. It does this for `Pinocchio`, despite it not having a duplicate.